# Log statement not being printed after replacing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Im writing a chrome extension for the first time. 
It calls a content script provided below. 
The script executes until the html is replaced, the console.log directly below it doesnt get run.

Does anyone know the reason for this?
Thanks

background.js:

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var r = /(\£?[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]))/gmi;
    var replaced = $("body").html().replace(r,"<span class='tooltip'>$1</span>");
    console.log("Herro");
    //console.log(replaced);
    $("body").html(replaced);
    console.log("after replacement");
    $('.tooltip').each(function(index) {
        console.log("in here");
        var price = $(this).text;
        price = price.substring(1, price.length);
        console.log(price);

    });

});
```

Comment: `console.log(price);` not works if your above code gets faiied any place.

Comment: Try wrapping the part that fails in a try / catch block and output the error.

Comment: @Jide Good advice, thank you!